# Debugger: unable to see values of my variables

Tags: objective-c, debugging, xcode4

This is what I see when using the debugger:

[image: Debugger Variable View]

Why can't I see the actual values?  (I assume it's a setting, but I haven't a clue what it would be).

Comment: Which value are you talking about? all are in hex because almost all are pointer.

Comment: So how do I see the "values" rather than the pointer?  (This used to show values, now it doesn't)

Comment: Nick:  I don't want to see what's in "self", but rather the local variables...

Comment: The screenshot is of Xcode 3.x, not Xcode 4.

Comment: jbrennan: whatever!  the output is the same, XC3 or XC4!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* see the actual values. `errmsg` is 0x0, `data` is 0x1d254, and so on. What you can't see right now is the summary, which usually shows you the contents of the object being pointed to. Sometimes this happens because the debugger is a little confused; sometimes it's because the variables really are out of scope. If you have any optimizations turned on, the compiler may be eliminating the variable in question. One clue here is that both `data` and `typename` have the same value, so at least one of those isn't valid at this point in the code.

If the debugger is just confused, one way to see the object is to use the gdb console. gdb has a `print-object` command, abbreviated `po`, that's very useful:

```
> po data
```

will do its best to print a useful value.

Comment: Thank you... I assume PO is the same as Print Description in the drop-down menu in XC..